# Send image to deep link URL in MSTeams

Tags: javascript, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I am trying to create a link for a chat that directly opens to a specified chat with a specific topic name and message. I am trying to send an image to that message. How is that possible?
and I am retrieving that image from the clipboard.

Deep link sample - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/deep-links#deep-linking-to-a-chat

Comment: Thank you for reaching out to us We will investigate and if we require further information we will reach out. Best regards, Teams Platform

Comment: Thanks a lot... Awaiting your response ! @Abhijit-MSFT

Comment: Currently you can create a deeplink with the text message only. You cannot send a image using the deeplink. Could you please check the docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/deep-links#generating-a-deep-link-to-a-chat)

Answer (score 1):

Currently you can create a deeplink with the text message only. You cannot send a image using the deeplink. Could you please check the docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/deep-links#generating-a-deep-link-to-a-chat)?